# Run Microsot Internet Explorer inside an iOS Application

Tags: ios, internet-explorer

Is there any way to run Internet Explorer inside an iOS Application? I am looking for a component, like WebView, which be able to open IE websites.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by an "IE website"? Do you mean a website that only functions when viewed with Internet Explorer and not other browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I mean websites which only operate correctly with IE.

Answer (score 0):

> The shortest answer is no, there's no IE for iPhone or iPad. Sorry to
>   tell you this, Internet Explorer lovers or those of you who are
>   required to use it, but there never will be.
>
> There are two key reasons for this:
>
> Microsoft stopped making Internet Explorer for the Mac in 2006. If the
>   company doesn't develop IE for the Mac, it seems very unlikely that
>   Microsoft would suddenly bring IE to the iPhone More importantly,
>   Microsoft doesn't make IE for any operating system anymore. The
>   company retired Internet Explorer completely in 2015 and replaced it
>   with a new browser called Edge.

Source : https://www.lifewire.com/can-you-get-ie-for-iphone-2000225